# What does the "GMS" abbreviation mean here?

Tags: fide, rating, terminology

I was wondered what the abbrevation meant here.
https://ratings.fide.com/profile/2027895/chart

"Period RTNG    GMS RAPID RTNG  RAPID GMS   BLITZ RTNG  BLITZ GMS"

From the context it seems a odd for it to mean Grandmasters.

Comment: It's unnecessary abbreviation. FIDE really couldn't spare a few letters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an abbreviation for "games". 0 means the player was inactive (no rated games played).

Comment: Makes perfect sense.